# Well-definedness of a map between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If we let $G=\langle\,g\,\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order n. The lecturer told that it is obvious that for any $ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ the map $ \varphi: G \rightarrow GL(\mathbb{C})$ given by $g^{m} \mapsto e^{\frac{m 2 \pi i k}{n}}$ is well-defined.

How do I know that the map is well-defined?

Is a map well-defined if $g=h \implies \varphi(g)=\varphi(h)$ for $g,h \in G$? 
If this is the definition of well-defined how do I show it?

Comment: Note that $g$ and $g^{n+1}$ represent the same element of the group $G$. On the other hand $\phi(g)=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}$ and $\phi(g^{n+1})=e^{\frac{(n+1)\pi ik}{n}}$. In order for the map $\phi$ to make sense, you at least need that $\phi(g)=\phi(g^{n+1})$. In general, you need to show that $\phi$ is uniquely defined independent of the choice of representant in the group $G$.

Comment: I know that the group is cyclic of order n. that means $\varphi(g^{n+v})=\varphi(g^v)$. Can I use this?

Comment: It is not only a well-defined map, it is an isomorphism.

Comment: No! How do you know that $\phi(g^{n+v})=\phi(g^v)$? I agree that $g^{n+v}=g^v$ but $\phi$ still sees the power. Note that $\phi$ as written above defines a relation, but not necessarily a function, that is precisely what you need to show. Also, you should remove $k$ from the question, it's a typo I think.

Comment: The $k$ is not a typo..

Comment: $\varphi(g^{n+v})=e^{2\pi i k } * e^{\frac{v 2 \pi i k}{n}}=1 * e^{\frac{v 2 \pi i k}{n}}=\varphi(g^v)$

Comment: That's correct and you're right about the $k$. I missed the "for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$" part :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and since $G=\langle g\rangle$, $g^m=g^l$ if and only if $n\mid m-l$. But then$$e^{2\pi ikm/n}=e^{2\pi ikl/n},$$since $e^x=e^y$ if and only if $\frac{x-y}{2\pi i}$ is an integer.

Comment: I don't understand this.. what happens with the "m" ? and does this show that the map is well-defined?

Comment: It shows that $g^k=g^l\implies\varphi(g^k)=\varphi(g^l)$. Are you disturbed by the fact that, instead of using the letter $m$, I used the letters $k$ and $l$?

Comment: okay! No its just that $g^{m} \mapsto e^\frac{m 2\pi i k}{n}$. and if you used the letters k and l instead of the letter m. what about the k in "$m 2\pi i k$". Im just confused now

Comment: Right. I missed that $k$ and I've edited my answer.

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: Can I ask an extra question? :) How do I show that $e^x =e^y$ if and only if $\frac{x-y}{2 \pi i}$ is an integer?

Comment: Because $e^x=e^y\iff e^{x-y}=1$ and $e^z=1\iff z\in2\pi i\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much